# PIC16F876A have signal oscillator

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I use PIC16F876A, with crystal 7MHz, capacitor 33nP and MCLR pull up with 10k. 
I am using software programmer IC-PROG 1.05D base AN585 programmer.
System doesn't work, Pin OSC1 and OSC2 no signal, how to solve this problem?

Regard
Bagus

Comment: Can you supply a circuit diagram.

Comment: Also your initialisation code would be helpful.

Comment: This is not a real question as it's incomplete, vague, and ambiguous in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see for yourself that your question is lacking much important information and is garbled.  We don't tolerate that level of sloppiness here.  This question will likely be closed soon, and I have already started that process.  However, in the mean time here are a few points.  If you address these by fixing your question before the question is closed, then you may still yet solve your problem.

Are you really sure the crystal is 7 MHz?  That's within the valid range, but it is rather unusual.

You should have two capacitors, not just one as implied by your saying "capacitor" (not plural).  There should be one cap to ground on each side of the crystal.

Nano-Pascals is not a unit of capacitance, as you should know yourself (duh).  If you meant "nF" (Nano-Farads), then that is way too much for any crystal I've ever encountered.  If in doubt, try *two* 22 pF (pico-Farad) capacitors to ground, one on each side of the crystal.  The datasheet shows the circuit to use.

What the heck is "doesn't work"?  The fact you can't see for yourself this is pretty useless information for debugging your setup remotely doesn't say much about you.  We have no idea what symptoms you expected to see to decide is works, obviously.

The OSC1 and OSC2 pins should have the crystal frequency on them.  However, particularly the OSC1 (input to processor) signal is very high impedance and a ordinary scope probe can kill the signal.  Use at least a 10x probe and check the OSC2 pin (output from processor).

You mention the programmer, which leaves open the question of whether you are having a problem writing the code into the PIC or whether the problem is with the code itself.  All decent programmers verify after write.  Was the program memory verfied successfully?  If not, then that's the problem.  If so, then the programmer you use is irrelevant.

What oscillator mode do you have selected in the config word?  For a 7 MHz crystal you should be using HS mode.

Show a schematic of *exactly how you have it hooked up*.  What is your power supply?  Have you measured it to make sure it is what you think it is?  What is the size and placement of the bypass cap?

Reply to *all* these issues clearly and directly by editing your question.  No hand waving, and no answering just what you want to or you think is relevant.  Do this quickly and it might save your answer from its current path of getting closed promptly.